# Specifying C library when compiling with buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I'm compiling a toolchain and rootfs with buildroot.

If I run `make menuconfig`, I can select *uClibc-ng* in *Toolchain/C library*.

That's fine, but now it compiles uclibc-1.0.32.

Unfortunately my target system has some internal programs which were originally linked to uclibc-1.0.26.

How can I instruct buildroot to compile a specific version of uclibc library?

I can run `make uclibc-menuconfig`, but it can only configure the current (1.0.32) version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for specifying package version by adding it to your `make` command:

```
make <PKG>_VERSION=1.0.26
```

Then buildroot will download the required package but you have to make sure you update the package's hash file with the hash of this version.